# Why some? returns true when it takes false as a parameter in Clojure?

Tags: function, clojure, functional-programming, lisp, clojurescript

I couldn't understand the intent of **some?** function in Clojure.

I need some function(**built-in**) that returns false when it takes (nil or false).

Here is the example:

```
(some? "1")
=> true

(some? nil)
=> false

(some? false) ;;Which is odd!!
=> true
```

Comment: The interesting thing is that `nil?` does exactly the same as `some?`.

Comment: @S4M No, it doesn't. `(nil? nil)` returns `true` whereas `(some? nil)` returns 'false`.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl you are right, it's `(not (nil? false))` that returns `true` and `(not (nil? nil))` that returns `false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the documentation of [`some?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some_q):

> ```
> (some? x)
>
> Returns true if x is not nil, false otherwise.
> ```

`false` is definitely not `nil` thus `(some? false)` returns `true`.

It is a complement of `nil?`

```
(= (some? x) (not (nil? x))
```

As @delta suggested, you can use [`boolean`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/boolean) to check if something is not `nil` or `false`.

Comment: i would add, that semantically `some?` totally corresponds to it's title, meaning that it checks, that value is *something*, while only `nil` is considered to be *nothing* in clojure. Obviously `false` is something. So there's nothing weird about this behavior.

Comment: @leetwinski Agreed, however, people are often confused because in `some` logical true values (i. e. not false) returned by the predicate are treated as a match. The naming is consistent there too, though, saying "Give me some element matching the predicate". Also the naming of `some->` is consistent, which again treats false as `some?` does.

Comment: Indeed.. I would rather name it `something?` really.. but well.. Rich knows better)

Answer (score 4):

Don't know why `some?` is like that. But what you are looking for is `boolean`.

---

1. https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/boolean

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler, use [IF](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if):

```
user=> (if "1" true false)
true
user=> (if nil true false)
false
user=> (if false true false)
false
```

Answer (score 1):

While there is more than one way to do what you are asking, I think the easiest is to use the `truthy?` & `falsey?` functions [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#the-truth-is-not-ambiguous):

> The Truth Is Not Ambiguous
>
> Clojure marries the worlds of Java and Lisp. Unfortunately, these two
>   worlds have different ideas of truth, so Clojure accepts both false
>   and nil as false. Sometimes, however, you want to coerce logical
>   values into literal true or false values, so we provide a simple way
>   to do that:

```
(truthy? arg)
  Returns true if arg is logical true (neither nil nor false);
  otherwise returns false.

(falsey? arg)
  Returns true if arg is logical false (either nil or false);
  otherwise returns false. Equivalent to (not (truthy? arg)).
```

Since truthy? and falsey? are functions (instead of special forms or macros), we can use them as an argument to filter or any other place that a higher-order-function is required:

```
(def data [true :a 'my-symbol 1 "hello" \x false nil] )

(filter truthy? data)
;=> [true :a my-symbol 1 "hello" \x]
(filter falsey? data)
;=> [false nil]

(is (every? truthy? [true :a 'my-symbol 1 "hello" \x] ))
(is (every? falsey? [false nil] ))

(let [count-if (comp count keep-if) ]
  (let [num-true    (count-if truthy? data)   ; <= better than (count-if boolean data)
        num-false   (count-if falsey? data) ] ; <= better than (count-if not     data)
    (is (and  (= 6 num-true)
              (= 2 num-false) )))))
```

Comment: I think the required function is `truthy?`, not `falsey?`.

Comment: Considering that logical truth is respected in all conditional forms by the language itself, I'd consider these predicates as adding readability at best 99.99% of the time. `falsey?` is exactly `not`. IDK the impl of keep-if, but consider idiomatic `(filter identity data)`, `(filter not data)` - I am not downvoting this because this is a good example of adding readability by contextual redefinition in SICP style but it would be better if you provided the one-line implementation here instead of linking to it, for learning purposes.

Comment: You are correct that the primary purpose is readability, so that that the text of the code says more literally what it intends to do. This is especially helpful to people learning Clojure. Using `not` isn't too hard to read, but there is no inverse analogous to `truthy?`. Of course, one cannot use `if` since it is a special form. Thus, the thin wrapper fn's `truthy?` and `falsey?` to coerce to `true`/`false`. While `boolean` works, I was using Clojure for 2 years before I ever noticed it! Even then, the docs make it appear to be a "cast" until you test & verify all of its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The effective [source for `some?`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L526) is

```
(defn some? [x] (not (nil? x)))
```

It would be better called `not-nil?`, which [Tupelo](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#tupelo-core-overview) offers as an alias.

As others have said, the function you are looking for is `boolean`.